# More Card layouts - Author and content?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

as seen here - https://developers.google.com/glass/design/style
there should be native implementation of Card "Author and content" but I cannot find how to use it.

In [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/Card) you can change layout (a bit) by

```
setImageLayout(Card.ImageLayout imageLayout)
```

but this is minor change.

How to get that "Author and content" card style (or any other without writing own Activity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your owns layouts for that kind of cards. You should follow  the style of https://developers.google.com/glass/design/style .

In https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets#xml_layouts you can find two .xml layouts that maybe help you.

Comment: It'd be awesome if Google had copy/paste XML layouts for: Full bleed with text, Author and content, and List as the do with the Main layout and Left image or column XML layouts...